# How does this ternary operation work without an argument being passed into the function?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm going through a tutorial on how to make true copies of properties that are objects and arrays.  This process is called deep copy. Here is the code that will do just that:

```
function deepExtend(source, destination) {
    for (var s in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
            if (typeof source[s] === "object") {
                destination[s] = isArray ? [] : {};
                deepExtend(source[s],destination[s]); 
            } else {
               destination[s] = source[s];
            }
        }
    }
    function isArray(o) {
        return (typeof o === "[object Array]");
    }
}

var person = {
    array1: [1,2,4,5],
    name: "Karen",
    address: {
       street: "1 Main St",
       city: "Baltimore"
    },
    scores: [212, 310, 89],
    say: function () {
         console.log(this.name + ", " + this.address.street + ", " +
               this.address.city + ", " + this.scores );
    }
};
var employee = { salary: "$45,000" };
deepExtend(person, employee);

employee.say();  // => Karen, 1 Main St, Baltimore, 212, 310, 89
```

In the ternary operation portion, how does a parameter get passed to the isArray function?

```
destination[s] = isArray ? [] : {};
```

Comment: It's not. That code is incorrect. You can check it by logging inside the `isArray` function, `isArray ? ` is just checking if the function is defined.

Comment: Thank you Sheng for the help.

Comment: Also that `isArray()` should use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). `typeof` won't return that string. Looks like a flawed tutorial